# Divert caller to Listen to Music in Android

Tags: android

I have googling about a way to somehow divert an incoming call(RINGING/OFF-HOOK state) to listen to an audio file. So far experts have commented that it is not possible to play music while in call. But is it possible, to divert a caller to a music file so that only he can listen to it ? Here I am referring to a HOLD kind of scenario. Please suggest.

Comment: Short answer, no it's not possible.